# Ideas about moviemaking

Tags: discussion, on-topic, topic-challenge

I have a question about my Worldbuilding Stack Exchange post: [making history true again](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/173589/making-history-true-again)

I have asked [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12963/is-asking-about-imaginary-movies-considered-good-questions-here) in another SE site and they introduced me to you.

I have asked but didn't find appropriate tags about ideas or movies.

Did I mistakenly ask here?

Comment: @Alexander please tell me.

Comment: worldbuilding is for asking questions about how to make a world. your post has no question. they sent you to the right place, this is for creating a world, but you must ask one specific and focused question.

Comment: from what i read of the link you provide, you want opinion or discuss or feedback about your idea right ? unfortunately this site not design for that, it purpose is to help creating imaginary world, though there some way to kinda become a feedback when the question is regarding the plausibility or possibility or realism of the imaginary world in description or context for example.

Answer (score 8):

What they actually said was this:

> Depending on the question you could try Worldbuilding. However, I think it would need to be a specific question relating to building the world. Asking in general as in: would this film idea work? Wouldn’t be acceptable there or any SE site as far as I know.

And this:

> If it's a question about the creation of fantasy worlds, then Worldbuilding SE might be a good bet [...] Before asking on any site, though, you should check their help centre to see if your question is likely to be acceptable there or not.

You did not follow their advice. The question you posted was not about worldbuilding, nor was it actually a question at all. You simply posted a brief summary of your storyline. My assumption is that you're looking for feedback on whether it's a good idea or not, but that is *not* what Worldbuilding is for. You were told that before you came here, and you ignored it.

To be clear: If you have any **specific problems** with developing **the world in which your film takes place**, then we can help you. If you have any problems with writing the actual plot of your film, we most likely cannot help you. And if you just want feedback on a story idea, then we definitely cannot help you.

Answer (score 5):

No, but you did not ask a question. You made a statement about a plot, but that was it, no problem for us to help you. What we need is a specific question like "How would [subject] work" or "what what can happen in [situation]?" not just a rundown of the plot. it is important to give info to the people who might answer so they can answer it well. But we **need** a question.

Answer (score 2):

The question you've asked isn't about worldbuilding as such. It's either a plot question or something deeply sociological about the need a society has for myths over and above the requirement for truth in historical recollection.

Answer (score 1):

**Where to go:**

This line of inquiry is definitely unsuitable on any Stack Exchange forum. Especially this one.

Since you're asking a general interest query about the direction you should take with your script / idea, I'd recommend a general purpose discussion forum like Reddit (r/worldbuilding or r/fantasyworldbuilding or r/scifi or r/sciencefiction).